# Remove Notification Bar but NOT Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is there a way to implement an ActionBar **without displaying the Notification Bar**(Clock, Battery, etc..) ?
If I set `"@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` I can't get the ActionBar using `getActionBar`, and if I use the `requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR)` function I get an error.

Can you please help me?

Comment: show on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379916/adding-an-action-bar-to-theme-black-notitlebar-android maybe there is a solution for you...

Comment: Thank you Stefan. I have read that question, but after reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569450/android-theme-fullscreen-and-the-action-bar?rq=1 I get the solution that there is no way to show an Action Bar in full screen mode :(

Comment: "Is there a way to implement an ActionBar without displaying the Notification Bar" -- not that I am aware of.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069660/how-can-i-keep-the-action-title-bar-but-hide-the-notification-bar

Comment: Check  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme) post.