# Menu Items are not showing on Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have made a completely new project. I have added items to the `menu` layout file. Those items do not show up on the action bar's right side. I remember that an icon with three dots shows up which opens up the menu.

[image]

Here is my `Activity`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));     
        actionBar.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And here is my `main.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_option1"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings34"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_option2"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings3"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_option3"/>


</menu>
```

Comment: On which device does this happen? Also, can you show us some code? It's relevant

Comment: Device is HTC One V. I am running CyanogenMod 10. I have updated the text @gunar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196368/android-want-to-show-3-dots-menu-on-ics

Comment: what is the version of your android os????

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Since you set the `showAsAction` attribute to `never`, then these menu items will never show as action views. Try this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/action_option1"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings34"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/action_option2"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings3"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/action_option3"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: What are the design recommendations from Google about this. Should use `ifRoom` or `never`

Comment: The best article I've seen about this is the one from developers. Pretty long so grab a beer and study it as it's the key to your app navigation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Answer (score 118):

### Context

There seems to be a misunderstanding about this `showAsAction` property in the menu configuration. The information I find in the many stackoverflow answers always seem to be incomplete. So here is an attempt to change that.

### Three dot | overflow | options menu

There is no way to control if your actionbar will show the three dot overflow menu or not in code.

*Well you can force it not to show by having no options menu for sure. And to be fair you can hack around this, more info at [How to force use of overflow menu on devices with menu button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286822/how-to-force-use-of-overflow-menu-on-devices-with-menu-button)*

**The dots showing or not depends on the device you're testing on**. Devices with a menu button will NOT SHOW the three dot icon on the actionbar since users can use the menu button on the device.

[image: options menu button on device]

Devices that don't have this options menu button (like the nexus devices starting from Galaxy) have no alternative to trigger that options menu. Running the same app on these devices will show the three dot overflow menu option in the actionbar.

[image: actionbar showing options menu]

### What you can control

There is the `showAsAction` option in the menu xml file that you can use to **control how that single menu option will show** up in the actionbar.

According to official [menu resource doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html) the options are:

```
android:showAsAction=["ifRoom" | "never" | "withText" | "always" | "collapseActionView"]
```

The **`ifRoom`** flag only shows the option if there is enough room. This should be your first choice in most cases. This will however condense the title in the actionbar (see vertical oriented screenshot).

The **`never`** flag will have this option always in the overflow menu and never directly in the actionbar.

The use of the **`always`** flag is discouraged since it will force the option to always appear in the acitonbar. Even if running on a very small screen size. This could render the title completely invisible.

As you might now an option menu can have both an `android:title` and an `android:icon` property. You can use the **`withText`** flag together with `always` or `ifRoom` (use a pipe `|` in between) to force the text of the item to show next to the icon when rendered in the actionbar.

The **`collapseActionView`** is only supported from `API level 14` so let me ignore that.

A screenshot showing the below code snippet in action on a device hold in portrait mode:

[image: collapsed title and mostly icons on vertical orientation]

And another screenshot where there is more space in the actionbar thanks to the landscape mode:

[image: landscape mode actionbar rendered]

### Android Documentation

The best development doc about this actionbar would be [the actionbar guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). If you're looking more [for design guidelines follow this link](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html). The [menu resource link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html) was listed before. For [menus in general check this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html).

### Code snippet

The code only for reference since that part seems to be right in most answers. A more complete example can be found at https://github.com/AndroidExamples/fragment-navigation

The `/res/menu/main.xml` file contents:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="be.hcpl.android.example.MainActivity" >

<!-- an option that never appears as a fixed text/icon in the actionbar -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_one"
    android:title="@string/action_one"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<!-- another option that only appears if there is enough room -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_two"
    android:title="@string/action_two"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<!-- a last option that always appears -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_three"
    android:title="@string/action_three"
    android:orderInCategory="300"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<!-- an option to show with both icon and text -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_four"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_directions"
    android:title="@string/action_four"
    android:orderInCategory="400"
    app:showAsAction="withText|always" />

<!-- an option to always show as an icon only -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_five"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
    android:title="@string/action_five"
    android:orderInCategory="500"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

### Some linked answers

- [Action buttons doesn't show up on Action Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512644/action-buttons-doesnt-show-up-on-action-bar)
- [Actionbar not shown with AppCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510337/actionbar-not-shown-with-appcompat)
- [Android - want to show 3-dots menu on ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196368/android-want-to-show-3-dots-menu-on-ics)

Comment: In fact, there is a way to force three-dots menu options to show up on the right side of action bar though I am not sure how legal this is. Refer to this SO answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27502405. Just for the sake of not loosing the code, I will post here the key lines ```ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this); Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");  if (menuKeyField != null) { menuKeyField.setAccessible(true); menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false); }```

Tested on Android Jelly Beans 4.2.2.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem. And I did all of the things that were said above. My problem was I forgot to override onCreateoptionMenu(Menu menu).

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I think you want to show the overflow menu icon on the top right always and want your menu to open from there. Try something like following to force it there:

Inside your `onCreate()` do:

```
  try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if(menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Ignore
    }
```

It will force the App to show the overflow menu. The menu button will still work, but it will open the menu in the top right corner. Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11438245/1306419) answer at [How to force use of overflow menu on devices with menu button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286822/how-to-force-use-of-overflow-menu-on-devices-with-menu-button) . This might be a kind of 'hack' but it works.

**Edit:**

Based on useful comments from @gunar, I request not to use this method. Following are the **reasons**:

- The private field `sHasPermanentMenuKey`can be refactored in a future
  releases. Your app will stop working then.
- Also If you force moving action items to action bar because you're
  used to them, you'll end up confusing users that are used to how apps
  run on their device. Those with hardware `menu` key will be used to
  have the options showed from menu hardware key. If you intentionally
  show them the three dots of overflow menu, it might confuse them.

So let all the apps be uniform in that sense. Those devices with no hardware key for `menu` items will show those automatically.

Comment: I've seen this before and it's a horrible hack.

Comment: Does anybody guarantee that private fields as `sHasPermanentMenuKey` will not be refactored in a future release? If so, above code will stop to work ... Also, if a device is not supposed to have an action overflow because it has an "options" hardware button, then it's natural to have a functionality and the top-right space could be used for something else.

Comment: Your users will be more used to your device, rather than with your app. If you force moving action items to action bar `because you're used to them like that` you'll end up confusing users that are used to how apps run on their device as `they're used to have the options showed from menu hardware key` :) Does it make sense?

Answer (score 7):

OR  you could create a structure like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu >
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_main"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_menu"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/menu_A"
    android:visible="true">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_settings1"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/menu_A1"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_settings2"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/menu_A2"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_settings3"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/menu_A3"/>
    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

Where the icon_menu you can create a new icon set with the three points icon clipart.

Answer (score 6):

Add

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

in the onCreate method.

Answer (score 2):

After searching and reading a lot of answer, I found that there is another little thing that you should pay attention to.

At least it was my problem and I didn't find an answer of any above. On your `.XML` file. Your `android:showAsAction=` shouldn't be form `android` package, it should be from `app` package like in the example below:

```
app:showAsAction=
```

Don't forget to import the `app` package.

Answer (score 1):

I had to set `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in `onViewCreated` or in `onCreate`

Answer (score 1):

Just write setHasOptionsMenu(true) in oncreate

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this function in onCreate function of the activity.

```
RequestWindowFeature (Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
```

Comment: Please try to spell correctly your sentences in order to keep a high quality in questions/answers on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

all answers above explained this issue well

but can we override this limitation and have the overflow menu item?!!

yes we can hack

```
 private void makeActionOverflowMenuShown() {
    //devices with hardware menu button (e.g. Samsung Note) don't show action overflow menu
    try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if (menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

and inside onCreate call it

references: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13098824/4251431

Answer (score 0):

add custom namespace like this to showAsAction and actionViewClass

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was changing a property in menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/gamingactivity_filter" android:showAsAction="ifRoom"   android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter"/>
```

this used to work in `Material` theme but didn't for `AppCompat` Theme & Activity so i changed how my menu.xml and add `app:showAsAction=` property under namespace `"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item android:id="@+id/gamingactivity_filter" android:showAsAction="ifRoom"  app:showAsAction="ifRoom" android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter"/>
```

from actvity inflate menu through `OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)`
and now from `OnOptionsItemSelected()` i can also  get the selected item id as

```
 public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
                switch (item.ItemId)
                {
                    case Resource.Id.gamingactivity_filter:
                        OnBackPressed();
                        break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```