# How to add an image with text in menu options in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-menu, android-icons

I'm trying to implement a customized menu option with both, text and image, which looks like this image:

[image: Menu Screenshot]

Unfortunately I don't know how to implement this.

My `menu.xml` looks like:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.ddcart.LIST">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings1"
        android:title="@string/action_settings1"
        android:orderInCategory="100" 
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings2"    
        android:title="@string/action_settings2"
        android:orderInCategory="100" 
        app:showAsAction="never" />

     <item android:id="@+id/action_settings3" 
         android:title="@string/action_settings3"
         android:orderInCategory="100" 
         app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

Comment: used this question is duplicate question of this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/28953241/5305430

Comment: these 2 other link which help you http://android-dev-talk.blogspot.in/2012_05_20_archive.html and http://stackoverflow.com/a/28238747/5305430

Answer (score 3):

If your Image is in `mipmap` dir then use

```
android:icon=@mipmap/your_image"
```

If your Image is in `drawable` dir then use

```
android:icon=@drawable/your_image"
```

for **icons** prefer adding four drawable each in

- drawable-hdpi   image size 36*36
- drawable-mdpi   image size 24*24
- drawable-xhdpi   image size 48*48
- drawable-xxhdpi   image size 72*72
- drawable-xxxdpi   image size 96*96

You can also use vector

create fine named **delete.xml** in drawable dir

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="24.0" android:viewportWidth="24.0" android:width="24dp">
    <path android:fillColor="#FFFFFF" android:pathData="M6,19c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h8c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2V7H6v12zM19,4h-3.5l-1,-1h-5l-1,1H5v2h14V4z"/>
</vector>
```

and in item tag use `android:icon=@drawable/your_image"`

Complete code

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings2"    
   android:title="@string/action_settings2"
   android:icon=@drawable/your_image"/>
```

For generation of **png** and vector use this [plugin](https://github.com/konifar/android-material-design-icon-generator-plugin)

Easily adjust color,size etc
Create **png** or **vector**

=> generate **png's** off all sizes on single click

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add `android:icon=@drawable/your_image"` in attribute to the item tag

```
 <item android:id="@+id/action_settings2"    
       android:title="@string/action_settings2"
       android:icon=@drawable/your_image"/>
```

and you need to use spinner refer these links http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Answer (score 2):

This way you can set icon to menu

http://keepsafe.github.io/2014/11/19/building-a-custom-overflow-menu.html

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext, v);
    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.album_overflow_menu);

    // Force icons to show
    Object menuHelper;
    Class[] argTypes;
    try {
        Field fMenuHelper = PopupMenu.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
        fMenuHelper.setAccessible(true);
        menuHelper = fMenuHelper.get(popupMenu);
        argTypes = new Class[] { boolean.class };
        menuHelper.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setForceShowIcon", argTypes).invoke(menuHelper, true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Possible exceptions are NoSuchMethodError and NoSuchFieldError
        //
        // In either case, an exception indicates something is wrong with the reflection code, or the 
        // structure of the PopupMenu class or its dependencies has changed.
        //
        // These exceptions should never happen since we're shipping the AppCompat library in our own apk, 
        // but in the case that they do, we simply can't force icons to display, so log the error and
        // show the menu normally.

        Log.w(TAG, "error forcing menu icons to show", e);
        popupMenu.show();
        return;
    }

    popupMenu.show();
}
```

**Output**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/setting"
        android:title="Setting"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:title="Profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/chat"
        android:title="Chat"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_chat_black_24dp"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please describe how the provided code solves the question?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the images as `icon` variable in the items of menu.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <group
            android:id="@+id/menu_top"
            android:checkableBehavior="single"
            >
            <item
                android:checked="true"
                android:id="@+id/drawer_gmail"
                android:icon="@drawable/gmail"
                android:title="Gmail"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/bluetooth"
                android:icon="@drawable/bluetooth"
                android:title="Bluetooth" >
            </item>
...
</group>


</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set a listview in the "menu" then by java code create a special adapter to inflate the "text and image together layout". Create a layout which contains a imageview and textview, use your special adapter to inflate and to transfer the result to listview so you will have a menu as how you wish.

If you have a error during doing these comment below..