# Action buttons doesn't show up on Action Bar?

Tags: android

I am following the tutorial on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com) and trying to add items on action bar.

Although i added all the code the search action shows as an overflow element instead of an action button element. I tried on 4" and 7" virtual devices with soft keyboard option.

Here is the

```
main_activity_actions.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Here is the `MainActivity.java` 's `onCreateOptionsMenu` method.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

[image]

I want to learn what causes this problem.

Comment: Could you provide a screen shot with the overflow visible?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a duplicate of that question...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is because if you use the support AppCompat ActionBar library and ActionBarActivity you should create your menus in a different than the standard way of creating xml menus in ActioBarSherlock or the default ActionBar.

So try this code :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
      <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          app:showAsAction="always"  />
      <item android:id="@+id/action_compose"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_compose"
          android:title="@string/action_compose" 
          app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: For anyone else with this same problem the 'xmlns' namespaces at the top of the xml definition are important.

Comment: @MarcF - why those are important ??

Comment: @Anjum - As in it wouldn't work for me without those declarations. Perhaps obvious to someone else but at the time it wasn't to me.

Comment: Thanks, this line [xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"] works for me.

Comment: @Anjum The namespace declaration must be written in order to achieve Support Library compatibility which is used for older API levels. Read more here: [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

Comment: @Muthuraja G : Your knowledge just saved my day... Thanks a ton !!!

Comment: For me it just display 2 icons =( i need more, even doing all this "tricks"

Comment: @Muthuraja, i have the same code but the action button isn't showing in the actionbar??

Answer (score 8):

Though the issue is resolved, let me post an answer with more information, may be found helpful by anyone later.

Now, the issue is you have used `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` and `android:showAsAction="never"`, instead if you would want to make action button always visible then use `android:showAsAction="always"`

FYI, android:showAsAction can take either of any values:

> android:showAsAction=["ifRoom" | "never" | "withText" | "always" |
>   "collapseActionView"]

[image]

You can read more about [Menu Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html)