# Action Button is hidden in overflow

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm following the [this Android tutorial.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html) However, I couldn't place the action button on the action bar. It is always hidden in the overflow. I looked up some related questions [Action buttons doesn't show up on Action Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512644/action-buttons-doesnt-show-up-on-action-bar) as well as this one: [Actionbar not shown with AppCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510337/actionbar-not-shown-with-appcompat)

But none of them worked for me.

My res/menu/main.xml looks like this:

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.gettingstarted.MainActivity" >

 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

 <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>

</menu>
```

And the src/MainActivity.java is as follows:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I created the folder drawable under /res and added the ic_action_search.png in that folder. Below is the what it looks like when I run the app.

[image: Hidden in overflow]

The Search is still hidden in the overflow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Highest Android API require:

```
<item
android:id="@+id/action_settings"
android:orderInCategory="100"
android:showAsAction="never"
app:showAsAction="never"
android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
android:title="@string/action_search"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
android:showAsAction="always"
app:showAsAction="always"
android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked out. But what is that app:showAsAction? Why it is needed? Could you explain a bit? Thanks!

Comment: I believe this applies to Android > 4.4 and/or to AppCompat library. Not sure.

Comment: It is explained on this page: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html "If your app is using the Support Library for compatibility on versions as low as Android 2.1, the showAsAction attribute is not available from the android: namespace. Instead this attribute is provided by the Support Library and you must define your own XML namespace and use that namespace as the attribute prefix." Read on for an example.