# The Overflow menu is not showing in samsung S3 but showing in samsung Note 2

Tags: java, android, xml

menus.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item
    android:id="@+id/my_account"
    android:title="@string/menu_account" />

  <item
    android:id="@+id/puenotes"
    android:title="@string/about_app" />

  <item
    android:id="@+id/about_developer"
    android:title="@string/menu_developer" />
  <item
    android:id="@+id/feedback"
    android:title="@string/feedback" />

  <item
    android:id="@+id/rate_us"
    android:title="@string/rate_us" />

  <item
    android:id="@+id/exit"
    android:title="@string/exit"
</menu>
```

Samsung S3 preview:

[image: Samsung S3 preview]

Samsung Note 2 preview
[image: Samsung note 2 preview]

So my question is how to show that overflow menu in all devices
    compilesdkversion 24

```
defaultConfig {

    applicationId "packagename"

    minSdkVersion 15

    targetSdkVersion 23

    versionCode 1

    versionName "1.0"
}
```

MenuInflater code:

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menus, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.puenotes:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, About_app.class));
            break;

        case R.id.my_account:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MyAccount.class));
            break;

        case R.id.about_developer:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Developer.class));
            break;

        case R.id.feedback:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Query.class));
            break;

        case R.id.rate_us:
            AppRater.ShowRatePopup(MainActivity.this);
            break;

        case R.id.exit:
            System.exit(0);
            finish();
            break;
    }
    //respond to menu item selection
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
```

This is my first question on sof but i need suggestion i dont expect SOF as a code getting technique.Please comment what i need to post.

Thank you !

Comment: Please show your menu inflater code

Comment: ANd also this menu is on fragment, or activity?

Comment: MainActivity (AppCompatActivity)

Comment: I have update inflater code

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159810/android-overflow-menu-button-is-not-visible-on-some-phones