# Actionbar logo is not coming in above 16 APIs

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar

i am working with ActionBar and i want to use logo instead of app_icon in ActionBar.
My code is working fine in ***API 16 but not in 17***.

Below is my code.

#### values/style.xml

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
   
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
       <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

 <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionBar">--><!-- Recent changes -->
      <item name="android:logo">@drawable/product_category_logo</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo|showHome|showTitle</item> 
    
    
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_theme</item>
  </style>



<style name="uiButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">290dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/textcolor_button</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_button</item>
</style>

<style name="uiEditText">
    <item name="android:layout_width">290dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/textcolor_button</item>
    <item name="android:hint">@drawable/rounded_edittext</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/loginHintColor</item>
</style>

<style name="starRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingstars</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">15dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">15dip</item>
</style>
```

#### values-v14/style.xml

```
<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseThemea" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
<!-- Recent Changes -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseThemea">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar"><!-- Recent changes @android:style/Widget.ActionBar-->
    <item name="android:logo">@drawable/product_category_logo</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo|showHome|showTitle</item><!-- Recent changes -->
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_theme</item>
 <!--<item name="android:backgroundStacked">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item> -->
</style>
<style name="MyActionBarTabText" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">               <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBarTabs" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">

    <!-- tab indicator -->
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>
</style>
```

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531174/android-action-bar-menu-not-showing-when-target-sdk-version-is-greater-than-10

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay what is the issue with this??

Comment: you have values-v14/style.xml
correspondingly do for 17 as well

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay still not working

Comment: oh ok..i will try and if will get solution perfectly than will be back to you!!

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay please.